# Adding custom properties to resource environment entries using wsadmin

Tags: websphere, jython, wsadmin

I'm able to add a resource environment entry using the following wsadmin command:

```
AdminResources.createResourceEnvEntries("myNode","myServer","ConfigurationProvider", "test", "test/zmtest")
```

However, I'm not sure how to then add custom properties to the resource environment entry I created.  I'm on WebSphere Application Server 8.0.

How can I add custom properties to my resource environment entries using wsadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should have searched a little more....details of how to do this can be found here...http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.base.doc%2Finfo%2Faes%2Fae%2Ftxml_envcustom.html